# How to get new record ID after native insert

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

For some good reasons i do a spring data jpa native insert.
The query gets executed in the right way.
But what i need is the newly generated table id getting generated by the `nextval('hibernate_sequence')`

Is there a way to get this id?

Here is my query:

```
/**
 * Inserts a new file attachment.
 * This is useful and maybe better suitable, because one may not want to load the whole
 * job offer to fullfill the JobOffer -> FileAttachment OneToMany Relation
 *
 * @param file       a given file
 * @param fileName   a given file name
 * @param jobOfferId a given job offer id
 * @return int the new id
 */
@Modifying
@Query(value = "insert into fileattachment(fileattachmentid, file, filename, joboffer_jobofferid) values (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), ?1, ?2, ?3);", nativeQuery = true)
int insertFileAttachment(String file, String fileName, long jobOfferId);
```

The int return value just gives the number of inserted records (1).
But i need the newly Id.
I don´t want to query it after the insert by another database query. Because if i have to, the whole native insert gets obsolete.

Does someone know an answer/Has someone alternative tips?
Thank you!
Kind regards
Thomas

**Edit**:
I use the native insert to avoid loading the whole joboffer record, which is a lot of useless data, just to persist the data the way with the entitymanager.

Instead i insert the data native.

Anyway your tip with the returning data from insert statements was very cool.
I was giving that a try and it is working. Thank you very very much!
I ended up with this solution:

```
/**
 * Inserts a new file attachment.
 * This is useful and maybe better suitable, because one may not want to load the whole
 * job offer to fullfill the JobOffer -> FileAttachment OneToMany Relation
 *
 * @param file       a given file
 * @param fileName   a given file name
 * @param jobOfferId a given job offer id
 * @return int the new id
 */
@Query(value = "insert into fileattachment(fileattachmentid, file, filename, joboffer_jobofferid) values (nextval('hibernate_sequence'), ?1, ?2, ?3) returning fileattachmentid;", nativeQuery = true)
long insertFileAttachment(String file, String fileName, long jobOfferId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get this id?

Not without querying the DB there isn't. Unless you are willing to use plain JDBC.

If your `FileAttachment` has a `@ManyToOne JobOffer offer`, why don't you just do the following:

```
FileAttachment attachment = new FileAttachment(file, fileName);
attachment.setJobOffer(entityManager.getReference(JobOffer.class, jobOfferId));
entityManager.persist(attachment);
entityManager.flush();
return attachment.getId();
```

This way, you will avoid loading the entire state of `JobOffer`. If the relation is unidirectional, I'm afraid you'll have to retrieve the entire `JobOffer`.

Alternatively, if you really must use a native `INSERT`, consider defining a stored procedure in your DB that would insert data and return the autogenerated id (see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/calling-stored-procedures-from-spring-data-jpa)).

Also, some databases (e.g. PostgreSQL) allow for returning data from `INSERT` statements (`INSERT (..) INTO FILEATTACHMENT RETURNING ID`). You would probably need to strip the `@Modifying` annotation, as the inserted id would end up in the result set of the query. You didn't mention which DB you were using, but the syntax looks Postgres-like, which is why I chose this example. If you're using another DB, consult the docs, maybe there's a similar feature.

However, I'd still recommend against using native `INSERT` statements in a JPA application. A lot of stuff can break. I suspect the method you're trying to implement is not part of a larger unit of work, but if that were the case, I'd be really careful.

Comment: Just to be curious ... entityManager.getReference(JobOffer.class, jobOfferId) does that work in client/server environment?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: Sorry crizzis, i misunderstood something about getReference. Please don´t mind my question any longer. Thank you for your useful help! Kind regards - Thomas.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using postgres you can simply do this. The key component is simply add a `RETURNING *` which will return all columns in inserted in table. You could then simply add a return type which will be mapped for you. This is in Kotlin which can be easily adapted to java as well. The Query syntax is native.

```
@Query(
    """ INSERT INTO table1 (a,b,c)
    select a,b,c from table2 where a = :someNumber
    RETURNING *;
    """, nativeQuery = true
)
fun addToProcessed(finOrVin: String): PojoEntityTest?
```

References:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 3):

Removing `@Modifying` annotation and keeping only `@Transactional` worked for me

```
@Transactional
@Query(value = "my query returning id",nativeQuery = true)
Integer importUserRecord(@Param("login") String user);
```

And in my service

```
Integer newId=userRepository.importUserRecord(user);
```

Comment: Note that we would need to add `RETURNING *` if its an object and just deleteing `@Modifying` is enough